# Disable on Parent Span Not Disabling Child Checkbox in Chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, google-chrome

So I have C# code that disables a checkbox:

```
chkbox.Attributes.Add("disabled","disabled");
```

This adds a new Span parent with disabled attribute to the chkbox.

```
<span disabled="disabled">
<input id="ctl00_DataContentHolder_chkbox" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$DataContentHolder$chkbox" checked="checked">
</span>
```

The checkbox is now disabled in IE but not in Chrome. How do I disable it in Chrome by modifying my C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   chkbox.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: I have conditions on back-end that I check before I disable that checkbox on page load. That's why I need C# code to disable it.

Comment: If I add onclick return false then the current functionality that enables the checkbox will have to be changed. Is there a way I can ensure that instead of creating a new span parent with disabled attribute the disabled attribute is added to checkbox itself?

Comment: I found that too. It does put the disable in the checkbox itself. In IE however it puts a disable attr in checkbox and also adds a span parent with disable attribute. I will have to make some script changes for enable functionality but this should work.